# R generate file names in loop

Tags: r, loops

I am iterating through a loop and with every step I would like to give the generated data a different name and save it to the workspace.

```
    for (l in 1:c){
      data_daily <- data_temp_daily[l,]
      data_daily_time <- data[(l:288*l),2]
      newfile <- paste("data_daily_day", l, sep = "") 
      newfile <- data.frame(data_daily_time, data_daily)
    }
```

newfile is the filename, which is correctly generated. However, I would like to save my df to the workspace with the newfile name! How can that be accomplished?

THANKS!

Comment: Check out `?assign`.  You should be able to use `assign(newfile, data.frame(....))`

Comment: Simply do not do this, but put these data.frames all together in a list. There are many answers on SO that explain why and how.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more info about your original datasets.

Let us imagine you want to use the `mtcars` data. 
You can easily `assign` rows or columns to your local environmment with

```
c = 5 
for (l in 1:c){
  assign( x = paste("data_daily_day", l, sep = ""), value = mtcars[l,] )
}
```

With `assign` you `paste` the name with `x =` and the data or values with `value =`. 
Here we are assigning each rows to our environment.

I can help you further because I dont know what is `data_temp_daily` and `data`. 
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer to this question here: 
[Dynamic Variable naming in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855818/dynamic-variable-naming-in-r)

You should google a bit before asking

Comment: Well, as googling is easier than putting a question here, let us assume that I have done that before. Thanks for the link anyway!